# NodeJS Passport function not getting called

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to make a Facebook login

```
var passport = require('passport');
var express = require('express');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: '-',
        clientSecret: '-',
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log("Token:", accessToken);
        console.log("Refresh token:", refreshToken);
        done(null);
    }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook',
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
    passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Helo");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

But why I never get the console logs from the function inside the FacebookStrategy ? 
The login works perfectly and I get redirected to the callbackURL but that function looks like it doesn't even get called

Comment: You get redirected to `callbackURL`. But does that mean the request succeeded, or is the same URL used for failure? Do you have to look in the request body or something to see whether it succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `initialize` `passport` before using its `authentication` strategies.

From Passport Documantation itself:

> In a **Connect** or **Express**-based application, **passport.initialize()
>   middleware is required to initialize Passport**. If your application
>   uses **persistent login sessions**, **passport.session()** middleware must
>   also be used.
>
> Note that enabling session support is entirely optional, though it is
>   recommended for most applications. If enabled, be sure to use
>   express.session() before passport.session() to ensure that the login
>   session is restored in the correct order.

add these lines before `passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({...})`

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your_express_session_secret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
```

Go through [Passport configure Documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) to understand it better.

Dont forget to `import` required `node modules`:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
```

Hope this helps!